# Xamarin Forms Add View to page on button press?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I have a view which is a collapsible list and I want to be able to press a button which says add another then it adds another view underneath the current one. is this possible to do in Xamarin Forms?

so every time a button is pressed add another one of these:

```
<local:TimeSheetAccordion HeaderText="Customer #1" BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20" />
```

page code:

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
            <local:TimeSheetAccordion HeaderText="Customer #1" BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20" />
            <local:TimeSheetAccordion HeaderText="Customer #2" BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20" />

            <StackLayout Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Button Text="Reset" BorderRadius="6" />
                <Button Text="Submit Time Sheet" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

page.xaml.cs Code:

```
private void AddAnotherButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainTimeLayout.Children.Add(new TimeSheetAccordion() {
            HeaderText = "Customer #1",
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FAFAFA")
        });

    }
```

is there a way I can set it so the HeaderText is incremented?

Comment: If you are talking about adding a new element to your list, the solution is actually to add an element to an ObservableCollection, on which your ListView would be binded. But I'm not quite sure that's what you want

Comment: Depending on what it is you want exactly this should be possible. But please provide us with some code of what you've tried so far and why that behaviour is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Knoop I haven't really tried anything as of yet but basically, I have the above view so on the function for the AddButton_Clicked{} i just want it to basically add it above the button

Comment: Can you post the entire code of your page? Is this view, to be added in a Listview?

Comment: Updated my code above to show the page code. its not in a listview just on its own

Comment: @SodiKZ125 mijn part in Bruno's answer is the fact that you `x:Name="somename"` the stacklayout you want to add your items to. This `x:Name` makes it so you can refer to this stacklayour (both in XAML and in codebehind) so after you've done that in the ClickCommand of your button you can access the stacklayour and add children to it (as in Bruno's answer)

Comment: @Knoop thanks for the help It is working now, Is there a way tho i want make the HeaderText increment when adding them as they just add using the standard string in the code.

Comment: @SodikZ125 sure you can just use the count of the stacklayout to determine the number: `HeaderText = $"Customer #{mainTimeLayout.Children.Count + 1}"`. Something along those lines should work

Comment: To add to that I advise you to use a dedicated StackLayout to store these items (otherwise the count will be wrong). That will also prevent them being displayed underneath the button if that's still an issue

Comment: this works exactly how I want it to now, thank you very much guys!

Comment: @SodiKZ125 You're welcome! Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a name to your StackLayout, to be referenced in your code-behind.

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout x:Name="mainLayout" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
            <local:TimeSheetAccordion HeaderText="Customer #1" BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20" />
            <local:TimeSheetAccordion HeaderText="Customer #2" BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20" />

            <StackLayout Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Button Text="Reset" BorderRadius="6" />
                <Button Text="Submit Time Sheet" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After this, in your Page.xaml.cs

```
mainLayout.Children.Add(new TimeSheetAccordion());
```

Comment: I have updated my question and fixed why it's spawning under the button I think!

Comment: you want to increment whats in the Text? You can just have a variable and increment when you add to the layout